# React: fetch api store data

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, async-await, fetch-api

I am pretty new with React so I struggle with combining useEffect , useState and async function to store the data fetched from API.

My problem is that once I leave fetch function which contains the state update, the state value reset (to empty) and I can't figure out why.

I use material react table MRT which will contain the data fetched. On each row, there s a column with a button that should open a modal with detailed information on the row. Rendering MRT with the data is fine. Modal opening is not OK. And I fetch all data (including the modal information) as soon as the table renders

Here is the part that doesn't behave correctly

```
  
 useEffect(()=> {
  const fetchData = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(POURL);
      const jsonData = await response.json();
      setCommandesListe(jsonData);
    } catch {....}
  };
  fetchData()
},[]);
```

So the table renders fine with the data after setting the state.
But if I check the value of CommandeListe in the console, it's empty .

I have noticed a very strange behaviour : CommandeListe is keeping its state (the data) when I hit save in my component's file. I am using Vite

therefore, rowid is undefined and the modal won't open
the column that open the modal is defined as :

I v already tried to add useEffect dependancies but it just keep triggering the fetchdata and the commandeListe.length remains 0.
`useEffect(()=> {....} ,[commandesListe]);`

Before using the fetch api , i used faker.js which worked fine with :

```
    const data:Icommande[] = Generer_Fake_Commandes(500); 
...
    const [tableData, setTableData] = useState<Icommande[]>(()=>data);
....
   <MaterialReactTable
        data={tableData}....
```

Now I i am running out of idea. Why my state reset after fetching and rendering the table ?

Here is the detailled part with console.log and example where I fetch one row:

```
const CommandesTable =  () => {
  const [commandesListe, setCommandesListe] = useState<Icommande[]>([]);
  useEffect(()=>{
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(POURL);
        const jsonData = await response.json();
        setCommandesListe(jsonData);
        console.log("right after set :" + commandesListe.length);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
      }
    };
    fetchData()
  },[]);
  console.log("after use effect : " + commandesListe.length)
  ...
  const [isModalOpen, setIsModalOpen] = useState(false);
  const [poToEdit,setPoToEdit]=useState<Icommande>();
  const onModalCloseRequest = (): void => {
    setIsModalOpen(false);
  };
  const fillModalWithCommandeDetails = (rowid:string)=>{
    console.log( " when openning modal :" + commandesListe.length );
    const commande = commandesListe.filter(commande=>
    commande.idCommande === rowid)[0];
    setPoToEdit(commande);
    setIsModalOpen(true);
    setCommandesListe;
    console.log("modal open");
  }

  const columns = useMemo<MRT_ColumnDef<Icommande>[] >(...
```

On page load the console log return this :

> right after set :0
> right after set :0
> after use effect : 1
> after use effect : 1
> right after set :0
> after use effect : 1
> after use effect : 1

and when I click the button to try to open the modal:

> when openning modal :0
> after use effect : 1

BUT when **I hit save on the file containing the code** the console log :

> after use effect : 1
> right after set :1

and the open modal click works :

> when openning modal :1

Comment: Starting to get really weird: there is only one case having the intended result : when save my file in the editor ! Every other way it doesn't work: if i refresh the page, if I wait , if I npm run dev, if i switch browser, it doesn't work

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: _"once I leave fetch function"_... could you please explain what you mean by this?

Comment: Keep in mind, that React mounts component twice when in development mode (to test correct setup of effects), so the effect will trigger one extra time. So if your endpoint returns empty data on second call, that is the issue.

Comment: _"if I check the value of CommandeListe in the console"_... don't do this. The console is not a debugging tool; your debugger is. I also recommend installing the [react developer tools](https://react.dev/learn/react-developer-tools) extension. But please [edit] your question to show exactly where this `console.log()` line is

Comment: @Phil . It occured yesterday when I posted the question. right after setting the state in the async function the usestate const changed. Now , according to the console.log , it's the opposite. either way it's empty when I change click the open modal btn unless I ctrl+S my file in the editor

Comment: I tried React.strictmode but it doesn't make any difference. Component still mounts multiple times also

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was that fillModalWithCommandeDetails() is defined on the same level as useeffect so the state set in useeffect,here commandeList, is null inside fillModalWithCommandeDetails(). All i needed to do is to pass the entire object commande to the function

Answer (score 0):

```
const fetchData = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(POURL);
    const jsonData = await response.json();
    setCommandesListe(jsonData);
    console.log("right after set :" + commandesListe.length);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
  }
}
     useEffect(() => {
       fetchData()
       },[]);
```

`//add open model dependancy`

You can try this.